# Text value is empty while extracting div text

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to extract the text "Quesadilla" , however when I try to get the text it comes as empty.

HTML trying to extract from:

```
 <div data-baseweb="block" data-testid="menu-item-name" class="d0 bd ib ic id ie be ed f7 bh fz if">
      <div lines="2" class="ig ih ii bq">Quesadilla</div></div>    
 </div>
```

Code:

```
menuItemNames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='menu-item-name']")
for menuItemName in menuItemNames:
   print(menuItemName.text)
```

Is there a better way to do this?
When I use the above code to get the text I get the values of some div while others return empty or null

Comment: If you know an unique identifier than you could. You could right click inspect then right click copy selector to do so.

Comment: The only unique identifier is data-testid='menu-item-name' . Around 10 divs with that tag. I want to get the text of all those 10 divs. But I get a few and some are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to introduce CSS_SELECTOR with explicit wait for more reliability :

CSS SELETOR :

```
div[data-testid='menu-item-name'] div
```

Code with explicit wait :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("Your URL")
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='menu-item-name'] div "))).text
print(ele)
```

if there are 10 elements inside this div `div[data-testid='menu-item-name']` you could properly try to use css selector like this :

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='menu-item-name']")
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

Learn more about explicit wait [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: This is assuming there is only one div with that tag. Can we use it if we had around 10 tags and get text of all of them?

Comment: Yes thats why i was using driver.find_elements_by_xpath as described in my question, so that it would get all the div with that tag and then get the text of all those divs. In your answer I can only get one value

Comment: @kibb : Updated the code with list of web element with css. The thing is if all 10 of them are visible to selenium then only you can extract the text. Visible in the sense it should be in view port. If there is any manual scroll down then you will have to automate that also